# Manipulating an array of strings and replacing them

Tags: python, arrays, string, data-manipulation

This is a problem which involves string manipulation.
For eg

```
unique_dates = ["January 12,1988","February 11,1995","December 2,1992"]
```

I want to now replace "January" with 1, "February" with 2 and so on. Also I need to remove the spaces and delimiters in between the two.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
unique_dates = ["January 12,1988","February 11,1995","December 2,1992"]
ans = []
for val in unique_dates:
  objDate = datetime.strptime(val, '%B %d,%Y')
  ans.append(objDate.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
print(unique_dates, ans)
```

refer datetime module in python

Answer (score 0):

First convert to a time object using `strptime` and then convert to the desired string using `strftime`. Can be done in one line as:

```
from time import strptime, strftime

unique_dates = ["January 12,1988","February 11,1995","December 2,1992"]

[strftime('%d/%m/%Y', strptime(i, '%B %d,%Y'))  for i in unique_dates]
>>> ['12/01/1988', '11/02/1995', '02/12/1992']
```